# Retrieve a pseudo element's content property value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$.each($(".coin"), function() {
    var content = "/*:before content*/";
    $("input", this).val(content);
});
```

I'd like to change the value of each input element using jQuery based on its pseudo element's `content` property value (`.coin:before`).

Here a example: http://jsfiddle.net/aledroner/s2mgd1mo/2/

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How i can do it? missing code /*:before content*/

Comment: I cannot understand, your code works, what do you want to have in the .coin inputs?

Comment: My code not work. Note that two first inputs have not value atribute, but the inputs after <h3>Final result</h3> yes. <h3>Final result</h3> is only the solution of problem, but the Jquery code not acts on these inputs. Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/aledroner/s2mgd1mo/3/. I only want to change /*before content*/ by the value of atribute 'content' of each pseudo-elemet

Comment: Where is the attribute `content`? I cannot see it.

Comment: In CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/aledroner/s2mgd1mo/3/

Comment: @Michelem See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to MDN,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) the second parameter to the [`.getComputedStyle()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)  is the pseudo element:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt]);
```

> pseudoElt (Optional) - A string specifying the pseudo-element to match. Must be omitted (or null) for regular elements.

Therefore you could use the following in order to get the pseudo element's `content` value:

```
window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').content;
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg64h546/)

```
$('.coin').each(function() {
  var content = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').content;
  $("input", this).val(content);
});
```

If you want to get the entity code based on the character, you can also use the following:

```js
function getEntityFromCharacter(character) {
  var hexCode = character.replace(/['"]/g, '').charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
  while (hexCode.length < 4) {
    hexCode = '0' + hexCode;
  }

  return '\\' + hexCode + ';';
}
$('.coin').each(function() {
  var content = window.getComputedStyle(this, ':before').content;
  $('input', this).val(getEntityFromCharacter(content));
});
```

```css
.dollar:before {
  content: '\0024'
}
.yen:before {
  content: '\00A5'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coin dollar">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="coin yen">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: But i need the result to be "\0024" not "$"

Comment: @aledroner You need to convert it. See this updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/vzxyv9ua/

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks!